# Which IoC framework in .NET has the most complete support for Xml configuration?

Tags: .net, xml, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I know that Xml for IoC configuration is out of the favor, but I plan to develop some tool support on top of it, so that is the reason for using Xml.
Also, I would suspect that Spring .Net could be a good choice, but the project seems to be abandoned. I have some experience with NInject, but Xml support seems to be very limited.

Comment: Even with tool support having XML configuration will never be better than code based configuration. There are simply too many scenarios that can't be expressed in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac) provides great [XML Support](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/XmlConfiguration), you can even use it on top of your programmatic configuration and split it into multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [NI.Ioc](http://nrecosite.com/ioc_container_net.aspx) (v2, v1 is also known as Winter4Net) for many years, this is really lightweight and very fast standalone DI-container with XML Spring-like syntax. It was specially designed to handle huge XML configurations (I've experience with 40mb configurations) automatically generated from high-level XML-based domain-specific models.

It lacks a bit of documentation but most answers may be found in unit-tests and source files.